# Multilines UITextView inside a dynamic sizing UITableViewCell gets wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm doing an iOS 8 app, I have 3 UITableViewCell in a UITableView, and I need them to dynamic change their height. I implemented it using Autolayout and add 2 lines of code in the `viewDidLoad` method as below:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

It works!

But the issues appeared, There is a `UITextView` in the second `UITableViewCell`. Sometimes it can not display long texts entirely, but when I rotate the device/simulator to the landscape mode, texts display correctly and entirely. here it is:

[image: ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/4aebd5d4gw1essboe2y4jj20o0130wkf.jpg]
[image: ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/4aebd5d4gw1essbozenu9j211s0p8gsb.jpg]

Sorry for posting a screenshot that include Chinese, but you can check the last line of texts and notice the number with blue font. The last line appears in landscape but portrait.

However, I turn it back to portrait from landscape, the entire texts are displayed well as landscape:

[image: ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/4aebd5d4gw1essbpghfpdj20o0130tf8.jpg]

Finally, there is another issue, the `UITableViewCell` list could get a wrong and overlapping layout sometimes as follows:

[image: ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/4aebd5d4gw1essbpzfefhj20o01300yi.jpg]

The cell with red line circled shouldn't be here!

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Maybe it's hard to answer by looking these screenshots, so I posted the code file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bust1s4b5u8vsm/contentTableViewController.m?dl=0)

I guess these issues could be related with Autolayout constraints. But I'm not sure with this. Any help here? I'll be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your project(as demo) ?

Comment: Sure, [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dlau31h6vmus25n/AAAuZk5FK5OhVu0GNkg8E7ooa?dl=0) @Bannings